# Material UI linked buttons with MUI's styled component api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I like the look of the [Material UI Styled Component api](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#styled-components-api) (***not*** the [styled-component library](https://www.styled-components.com/)), but I'm having trouble turning my simple button component into a linked button.

**How do I insert a react-router-dom link into a MUI Styled Component button?**

Previously, the typical [Material UI HOC api](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api) approach let me add a linked "reports" button as follows. It works great, but requires a lot more boilerplate (not shown here):

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  className={classes.button}
  component={Link}
  to="/reports"
>
  <ShowChartIcon className={classes.buttonIcon} />
  Reports
</Button>
```

[image]

**#1 Obvious Approach:** When I follow this pattern and include the `component` and `to` properties my own MUI Styled Component called `<MyButton>`, I get a typescript error saying those properties don't exist.

[image]

**#2 Different Approach:** Following the pattern proposed in [this material ui github issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9106#issuecomment-451270521), the button does indeed link to the reports screen, but the mui `variant` and `color` are lost:

```
<MyButton
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    {...{
        component: Link,
        to: `/reports`
    } as any}
>
    <MyShowChartIcon />
    Reports
</MyButton>
```

[image]

**#3 Workaround Approach:** A less desirable option is to wrap the button in a `<Link>`. That does create a working link, but it also brings in a little bit of unintended styling.

```
<Link to="/reports">
    <MyButton
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
    >
        <MyShowChartIcon />
        Reports
    </MyButton>
</Link>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the latest version of material-ui (v4.0.2) you can use the HOC component created with `withStyles`, but you will have to manually cast the custom component back to its original type:

```
const MyButton = withStyles(
  createStyles({
    root: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  })
)(Button) as typeof Button
```

then you can use your custom component like you would the original one:

```
<MyButton component={Link} to="/blank-page">
  my button
</MyButton>
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/createreactappwithtypescript-n6wih

I found this solution from this comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15695#issuecomment-498242520.